# Float sum broken?

Tags: python

```
print(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3)
```

returns

```
False
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not broken, that's how floating point arithmetic works.

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

I recommend reading this http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html

Answer (score -1):

It's a floating point precision issue. Basically floats cannot all be represented accurately in binary (and thus the underlying functions are working with imprecise representations of the numbers that you intend to use). Try using decimal.Decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal
print Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.2')
```

Comment: This does not work either.

Comment: SO won't let me remove my downvote :(. The most important part of this answer is to pass `Decimal` STRINGS not floats.